# Activatione failed - Nokia SDK for Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, nokia-s40

I am trying to install Nokia SDK kit for Netbeans. Following [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Getting_started/NetBeans/) procedure, I went to Tools and selected plugins and installed the plugin named JAVA ME SDK. On activating it, I am getting the following error,

> Activation failed: Not all requested modules can be enabled:
>   [StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.javame.kit jarFile:
>   C:\Users\Fahad.netbeans\7.1\modules\org-netbeans-modules-javame-kit.jar]

Please help me out to resolve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7, try to install everything out of the Users folders. The Windows' permissions must affect to your sdk or applications